# UPDATE with multiple conditions in list

Tags: sql, oracle, list

In Oracle,

I have a *table1* with 3 columns *id01, id02, id03* for example.

I needed to change the *product* column to 3

Through a *select B* I obtain the following result:

```
id01 id02 id03
1    8    9
5    3    7
4    2    0
7    7    8
```

How can I UPDATE the *table1* for all rows that meet each select row *select B*?

I thought of something like that but it doesn't work

`UPDATE table1 A SET A.product = 3 WHERE (A.id01, A.id02, A.id03) IN (SELECT B)`

Comment: you want to do this?  update table1 set product = 3 where (id01,id02,id03) in (select id01,id02,id03 from B)

Comment: yes, does oracle understand this type of expression and does it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> select * from b;

      ID01   ID02       ID03
---------- ---------- ----------
     1      8          9
     5      3          7

SQL> select * from table1;

   PRODUCT   ID01       ID02       ID03
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     0      0          0      0
     1      1          8      9
     2      5          3      7
     3      3          3      3
     4      4          4      4

SQL> update table1 a set a.product = 3 where (id01, id02, id03) in (select * from b);

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from table1;

   PRODUCT   ID01       ID02       ID03
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     0      0          0      0
     3      1          8      9
     3      5          3      7
     3      3          3      3
     4      4          4      4

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN` with multiple columns as follows:

```
UPDATE table1 A SET A.product = 3 
WHERE (A.id01, A.id02, A.id03) IN (SELECT id01, id02, id03 from B)
```